# why picocom gets irrecognizable code

Tags: uart

When I use picocom inspecting the print out of my program, it just prints �]��]�, I tried all the encoding settings in the run configuration of SDK. 
I am using Xilinx Zynq7000 SOC, ubuntu OS. 
Are there any problems with encoding settings of picocom?

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue to me.  �, or U+FFFD, is the Unicode replacement character, and means "I have no idea what this is".  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

Comment: so, is anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Since picocom is a terminal emulator program, and you fail to mention any serial port configuration (e.g. baudrate, data length, etc.), you probably have a simple case of an unconfigured terminal.

Comment: sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB2

Comment: `sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB2`    I only configure the baudrate. I don't know any other configurations?

Comment: The "correct" serial line parameters are what the other connected device is using, i.e. how is the Xilinx Zynq7000 board configured?

Comment: Should I configure it at the Run Configurations>>GDB >> STDIO Connection  in Xilinx SDK? I tried, but not works.  So where should I do that configuration. By the way, when I power up the board, the UART test is OK.